# Firebase deploy - Cannot find module of a local dependency

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I've got a submodule named `shared` which is located next to the `backend` folder (which is the cloud functions folder):

[image]

I've added the local dependency `shared` in `backend/package.json` like so:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "shared": "file:../shared"
}
```

I ran `npm install` and made sure that `node_modules/shared` exists. Although, When I run the following code:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

I get the following error (by firebase):

```
Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'shared/common'

Try running "npm install" in your functions directory before deploying.
```

This error is due to this line:

```
import { currentWeek } from 'shared/common';
```

If I change the directory to `../../../shared/common`, firebase will compile without any errors.

---

#### shared/common/index.ts:

```
export { currentWeek } from './current-week';
```

#### shared/tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "removeComments": true
  }
}
```

#### backend/tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*",
    "../shared/**/*"
  ]
}
```

---

Why do I get this error if I DO have this module? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: did you ever figure out a solution to this? Having the same problem

Comment: @Jonovono no, I had to import it relatively (../../)

Comment: @Jonovono I found a solution. Please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76380727/416029) below :)

Answer (score 2):

While @jrasm91's answer explains the reason for this error well, I kind of miss the solution to the problem here.

Let's assume you have the following monorepo structure

```
- common
- firebase
  - functions
```

where `common` is a NodeJS module with common code, `firebase` is the root folder of your Firebase project and `firebase/functions` is the NodeJS project of your functions.

In `firebase/functions/package.json` you cannot include your `common` module like

```json
"dependencies": {
    "common": "file:../../common"
}
```

because as @jrasm91 explained, the folder `common` is placed outside of the `functions` folder and thus won't be packaged and uploaded when running `firebase deploy --only functions`, which is also explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/handle-dependencies#including_local_nodejs_modules).

The solution that worked for me is to additionally symlink the `common` folder into the `functions` folder

```
cd firebase/functions
ln -s ../../common common
```

and then update the `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "common": "file:common"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, you have to config `module-resolution` in for typescript compiler.

For your case:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".", // This must be specified if "paths" is.
    "paths": {
      "shared/*": ["../shared/*"] // This mapping is relative to "baseUrl".
    }
  }
}
```

You can named `shared` by another name.

```
{
      "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".", // This must be specified if "paths" is.
        "paths": {
          "myLib/*": ["../shared/*"] // This mapping is relative to "baseUrl".
        }
      }
    }
```

Usage:

```
import { currentWeek } from "myLib/common";
```

Comment: If I add the `shared` folder to `paths`, then I'll have to add it to `include` too, which results in the same error. The only difference is that `shared` won't be in `node_modules` (which again leads to the question - why would firebase fail to find it? I assume it runs npm install externally which results in 404.

Answer (score 1):

In short:

1. `node_modules` is ignored by default, while `backend/dist` is uploaded.
2. `npm run build` happens locally and `npm install` happens in the cloud.
3. `npm install` probably fails in the cloud because of missing `shared` folder or wrong path issues due to a different directory structure and/or a different "root" directory in the cloud environment.

Or, in more detail:

Functions has a predeploy step that *builds* (`npm run build` => `tsc`) the typescript project locally and then pushes the output to the cloud where the dependencies are *installed* (`npm install`).

When you include `shared` via a relative path (`../../shared`) the compiled code is output to the `backend/dist` folder after the project is *built* (locally) and thus is uploaded.

When you include `shared` via a local node modules dependency, the output is in the `backend/node_modules` folder after the dependencies are *installed* and thus it is not uploaded as `node_modules` is ignored by default.

The other issue you are seeing is why `npm install` can't install the local dependency in the cloud. This is likely due to either (1) not uploading `shared` alongside `backend` and/or the directory and relative path structure in the cloud environment is different from what it is locally.

`firebase.json`

```json
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": ["npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint", "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"],
    "source": "functions",
    "ignore": ["**/.env", "**/.runtimeconfig.js", "**/.log", "**/node_modules/**"]
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Sven was really useful, I figured out another posible solution:
Using Firebase's predeploy script to handle this issue. Instead of creating a symlink, we could build and copy the necessary shared code into the functions folder prior to the deployment. Here is how it can be done:

In the firebase.json file:

```
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix ./shared run build",
      "cp -r ./shared/lib/* ./functions/shared/"
    ]
  }
```

and then update the package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "shared": "file:shared"
}
```

This way, all required shared code gets moved into the functions directory before deployment, thus avoiding the issue of Firebase not being able to locate the shared module.